# PHP Download file to server

Tags: php, curl, fopen, fclose

I am trying to download images using curl from php, however instead of saving the image to the server it is just outputting random characters to the web browser screen, here's the code

```
$final['IMAGE'] = 'http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png';

$imagename = trim(basename($final['IMAGE']));

$url  = $final['IMAGE'];
$path = '/media/import/';
$path .= $imagename;

$fp = fopen($path, 'w');

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`curl_exec($ch);` will print the output directly to the screen. You can stop his behavior when using the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`-option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

See the PHP-manual "[curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/de/function.curl-setopt.php)" for more information.

**Edit**

This little script downloads the file to a writable directory:

```
// file handler
$file = fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . '/test.png', 'w');
// cURL
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'somethinsomething.com/something.png');
// set cURL options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// set file handler option
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
// execute cURL
curl_exec($ch);
// close cURL
curl_close($ch);
// close file
fclose($file);
```

This time it's the `CURLOPT_FILE`-option that does the trick. More information can be found on the same link as before.

Comment: Changing it to use, curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
still doesn't not download the image to the /media/import/ directory

Comment: thank you its a great answer and you can download anything to your server , and big files take seconds to downloads

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure they will be .png, you can make use of imagecreatefromstring() and imagepng():

```
$c = curl_init( $final['IMAGE'] );
curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
$binary = curl_exec( $c );
curl_close( $c );

$imagename = trim(basename($final['IMAGE']));
$url  = $final['IMAGE'];
$path = '/media/import/';
$path .= $imagename;

$img = imagecreatefromstring( $binary );
imagepng( $img, $path, 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use copy():

```
copy("http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png", "/media/import/logo3w.png");
```

Comment: Running that still doesn't copy the file to my server at, /media/import/ nor do any errors come up